# Taggit gets wrong tags

Tags: django-taggit

I have a Work model with Category Foreign Key.  I am doing  -->

```
drawingTags = Tag.objects.filter(Q(work__category__slug_en = 'drawing') |
                                 Q(work__category__slug_en = 'illustration') |
                                 Q(work__category__slug_en = 'sketch') |
                                 Q(work__category__slug_en = 'storyboard'))
```

I get also the tags that do not belong to drawings ?  Am i doing smt wrong ?

-- EDIT --

I did a little test.  I have two applications named blog and web.
In blog i have 'entry' model and in web i have 'work' model. Both of those models have TaggableManager fields named tags...

When i want to take the tags of works categorized under drawing and do -->

```
drawingTags = Tag.objects.filter( work__in = drawings ).distinct()
```

If  there is a drawing with id 1  and if entry model has an entry with id 1. Than i get both item's tags.  I think there is a problem here but i do not know how to solve the puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType  

contentType = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Work)
drawingTags =Tag.objects.filter(taggit_taggeditem_items__content_type=contentType, 
                                        work__in = drawings ).distinct()
```